# Mapping a text file to a Map using Java's lambda and streams

Tags: java, collectors

So my text file contains 5 fields, i would like to create a `Map<Pair<String, String>,List<List<String>>>`
from of it, where Pair is an instance of Apache's `ImmutablePair`having 2 of the 5 fields as key, the value of that Map would be a `List<List<String>>` where each `List<String>` for the key, would contain the remaining 3 fields, so if the file would be like:

```
A,B,1,2,3
A,C,4,5,9
A,B,3,4,5
A,C,5,6,7
```

The result Map would be like:

```
K:(A,B)
 V:((1,2,3),(3,4,5))
K:(A,C)
 V:((4,5,9),(5,6,7))
```

I am trying to achieve this by making as much as possible use of lambdas and streams, here is my temporary code,, which works, but it returns as value the entire line:

```
  private Map<Pair<String, String>, List<List<String>>> createMultimapFromFile() {
    Map<Pair<String, String>, List<List<String>>> map = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(MAPING_FILENAME)))
        .lines()
        .map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(COMMA)))
        .filter(lineAsList -> lineAsList.size() == REQUIRED_FILE_LINE_LENGTH)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(filteredLine ->
            ImmutablePair.of(filteredLine.get(1), filteredLine.get(2))));
    return map;
  }
```

This call to `Collectors.groupingBy` makes use of [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) implmentation, which defaults to returning the map values as `List<T>`but what i would like and i cannot find is returning a sublist, to save space in memory.
I was under the impression that [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) is the right method, as the description says...
"and then performing a reduction operation on the values associated with a given key using the specified downstream Collector."
Is just cant find a pre made Collector where i can specify the code to finalize the list.
Anyone has any tip?

Comment: Consider making a class to represent your records, and perhaps the key (instead of `Pair`). This will add a lot to the readability of not only the parsing code, but all the code that uses the parsed data. Java is a strongly typed language. Trying to grok a maze of maps, lists, and boxed types is wearisome for your reader. Also note, neither your example or the other answers here close the stream. This is very bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collectors#mapping` would do the work for you.

```
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(MAPING_FILENAME), "utf-8"))) {
  return reader.lines()
    .map(line -> line.split(","))
    .filter(lineAsList -> lineAsList.length == REQUIRED_FILE_LINE_LENGTH)
    .map(data -> Pair.of(ImmutablePair.of(data[0], data[1]), Arrays.asList(data[2], data[3], data[4])))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getLeft(), Collectors.mapping(p -> p.getRight(), Collectors.toList())));
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

And Output would be like this,

```
{(A,C)=[[4, 5, 9], [5, 6, 7]], (A,B)=[[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]}
```

`Pair` is tuple from apache commons-lang library. Using here just to hold values. You can use any other object for that purpose.

alternatively, can be written like this as well

```
.map(data -> Pair.of(ImmutablePair.of(data[0], data[1]), Arrays.asList(data[2], data[3], data[4])))
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> p.getLeft(), Collectors.mapping(p -> p.getRight(), Collectors.toList())));

//without pair
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(data -> ImmutablePair.of(data[0], data[1]), Collectors.mapping(data -> Arrays.asList(data[2], data[3], data[4]), Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Closing that stream was probably more important than solving the initial question. Thank you!

Comment: There is no need for the `.map(data -> Pair.of(…,…))` step. The two arguments to this `Pair.of()` call are precisely what you could use directly in the subsequent `collect` operation, instead of `getLeft()` and `getRight()`. And you should specify an encoding to the `InputStreamReader`, as the embedded resource surely has a fixed encoding, which doesn’t change when the software runs on a different target system.